# Center align site logo in resposive blog theme

Tags: drupal, alignment, center

I am using the responsive blog theme and having a tough time centering my site logo.      This is what my site-logo in style.css looks like (according to inspect element):

```
#header img {
  margin: 0 0.75em 0 1em;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#header #site-logo { 
  margin-left: -82.5%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2.5em 0;
}
```

I tried changing the margins, text aligns and floats of these two divs, but none helped. I don't know, if I have to look into any other ID or class on the style.css.

Comment: place your logo in a div, and dont apply any floats, any margins or paddings. Just apply css like text-align:center . When you apply any sort of floats, the contents will go in that direction. Just apply text-align:center and try

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the logo just use margin:0 auto; http://jsfiddle.net/NVLtM/

```
#header #site-logo {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you don't know the width, make the image an inline-block element and use text-align:center on the parent element http://jsfiddle.net/NVLtM/1/.

```
#header {
  text-align:center;
}

#header #site-logo {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the float, remove existing margins, no need for width;

margin: 0 auto will center the element